# Is that a good idea to use transfer learning in real world projects?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

## SCENARIO

What if my intention is to train for a dataset of medical images and I have chosen a coco pre-trained model.

## My Doubts

1 *Since I have chosen medical images there is no point of train it on COCO dataset, right? if so what is a possible solution to do the same?*

2 *Adding more layers to a pre-trained model will screw the entire model? with classes of around 10 plus and 10000's of training datasets?*

3 *Without train from scratch what are the possible solutions , like fine-tuning the model?*

**PS** - let's assume this scenario is based on deploying the model for business purposes.

Thanks-

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a good idea to reuse the Pre-Trained Models or Transfer Learning in Real World Projects, as it saves Computation Time and as the Architectures are proven.

If your use case is to classify the Medical Images, that is, Image Classification, then

1. > Since I have chosen medical images there is no point of train it on
   >   COCO dataset, right? if so what is a possible solution to do the same?

Yes, COCO Dataset is not a good idea for Image Classification as it is efficient for Object Detection. You can reuse `VGGNet` or `ResNet` or `Inception Net` or `EfficientNet`. For more information, refer [TF HUB Modules](https://tfhub.dev/s?module-type=image-augmentation,image-classification,image-feature-vector,image-generator,image-object-detection,image-others,image-style-transfer,image-rnn-agent).

2. > Adding more layers to a pre-trained model will screw the entire model?
   >   with classes of around 10 plus and 10000's of training datasets?

No. We can remove the Top Layer of the Pre-Trained Model and can add our Custom Layers, without affecting the performance of the Pre-Trained Model.

3. > Without train from scratch what are the possible solutions , like
   >   fine-tuning the model?

In addition to using the Pre-Trained Models, you can Tune the Hyper-Parameters of the Model (Custom Layers added by you) using [HParams of Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/hyperparameter_tuning_with_hparams).